# Amazon: Product not showing in inventory list on seller central

Tags: amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral

Any one experienced with Amazon MWS might help me. I am trying to push a product through XML to my inventory in my seller central account. But it doesnot appear on there.

I am using sample file provided by Amazon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>merchant_id</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
  <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
   <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
      <SKU>56789</SKU>
      <StandardProductID>
        <Type>ASIN</Type>
        <Value>B00AK3RCQM</Value>
      </StandardProductID>
      <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
      <DescriptionData>
        <Title>Example Product Title</Title>
    <Brand>Example Product Brand</Brand>
    <Description>This is an example product description.</Description>
    <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 1</BulletPoint>
    <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 2</BulletPoint>
    <MSRP currency="USD">25.19</MSRP>
    <Manufacturer>Example Product Manufacturer</Manufacturer>
    <ItemType>example-item-type</ItemType>
  </DescriptionData>
  <ProductData>
    <Health>15
      Amazon Marketplace Web Service Feeds API 15
      Section Reference (API Version 2009-01-01)
      15
      <ProductType>
        <HealthMisc>
          <Ingredients>Example Ingredients</Ingredients>
          <Directions>Example Directions</Directions>
        </HealthMisc>
      </ProductType>
    </Health>
  </ProductData>
</Product>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Response looks like

```
FeedSubmissionId 7409597458

FeedType _POST_PRODUCT_DATA_

SubmittedDate 2013-06-25T12:24:45Z

FeedProcessingStatus _SUBMITTED_
```

Comment: If your response is stuck at `_SUBMITTED_` (which can occasionally happen for an extended period of time) it will not update as it needs to show `_DONE_`. Take a look at the scratch pad and see what your current response is: https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html, assuming its _DONE_, has your inventory updated? If it's not _DONE_ what is the status?

Comment: What is the "15
      Amazon Marketplace Web Service Feeds API 15
      Section Reference (API Version 2009-01-01)
      15" for? That's not supposed to be there is it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Amazon MWS Reports API to get the detailed report response, You just submit the FeedSubmissionId and wait for a response - the response will have the details why Amazon did not accept your file. here is a link to the documentation:
https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html?ie=UTF8&section=reports&group=bde